# Derivative of Matrix, Dimension Change Not the Same Shape.

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus

When I take the derivative of:

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial\mathbf{X}} \sum_{i,j}\mathbf{A} \odot log(\frac{\mathbf{A}}{\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{X}\mathbf{C}}) = \frac{\mathbf{A} \odot \mathbf{K}}{\mathbf{B}^T\mathbf{X}\mathbf{C}}
$$

where

$$
\mathbf{K} \leftarrow \sum_j \mathbf{C}^T \otimes \mathbf{B}^T 
$$
Why does the derivative have a different dimension than X? When I run autodiff I get the same dimension as X.

K has the same dimensions as A. Division is elementwise division. Also since K is the j sums it must be reshaped to have the same dimensions as A, it is also possible to sum along i and reshape to the same dimensions as X.

The process largely follows page 6 and 7 of:

https://www.jjburred.com/research/pdf/jjburred_nmf_updates.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Write the objective function $\phi$ in terms of the elementwise logarithm, elementwise division, and the matrix inner product. Then calculate its differential and gradient with respect to the $X$ matrix.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= A:\log\LR{\frac{A}{B^TXC}} \\
  &= A:\log\LR{A} - A:\log\LR{B^TXC} \\
d\phi &= -A:\LR{\frac{B^TdX\,C}{B^TXC}} \\
  &= -\LR{\frac{A}{B^TXC}}:B^TdX\,C \\
  &= -B\LR{\frac{A}{B^TXC}}C^T:dX \\
\grad{\phi}{X}
  &= -B\LR{\frac{A}{B^TXC}}C^T \\
}$$
where $(:)$ denotes the matrix inner product, which can be expressed in terms of the trace
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{AB^T} \\
A:A &= \big\|A\big\|^2_F \\
}$$
Note that this product commutes with elementwise division $(\oslash)$ and multiplication $(\odot)$, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:\LR{B\odot C}
 \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij}C_{ij}
 \;=\; \LR{A\odot B}:C \\
}$$
Also note that the gradient derived above has the same dimensions as $X\,$ (as expected).

Comment: Could you please explain how to take the derivative of $-A:log(B^TXC)$? in step 2? I know about the chain rule for logs, like $\frac{\partial}{\partial X} log(B^TXC) = \frac{\frac{\partial}{\partial X}B^TXC}{B^TXC}$... but I'm not making the connection.

Comment: By the way the trace inner product is really awesome, that's going into my toolbox of techniques. Also the commuting with hadamard products / division is also interesting.